# У меня есть код для бота в дискорде, но там не работает ephemeral=True

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

помогите решить проблему. код:

```
async def start(ctx):
    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(color=2,
                                       title="Добро пожаловать!",
                                       description="бла бла бла"), ephemeral=True)
```

когда пишу команду, выводится просто сообщение видное для всех

версия discord.py - 2.3.2

Answer (score 0):

**ctx не interaction!**

Отправить эфимерное сообщение невозможно через ctx. Только через интеракцию. Тоесть через слеш-команды а не текстовые!

Вывод: плохо читал документацию

Comment: Так слеш-команды не работают на этой версии discord.py блин! Объясни как сделать слеш-команду на этой версии

Comment: 2.3.2 на данный момент самая последняя поддерживаемая версия библиотеки. Слеш команды на ней точно поддерживаются. Вот пример базового создания слеш команд: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples%2Fapp_commands%2Fbasic.py. Но я бы советовал перейти на disnake. Discord.py на данный момент малоподдерживаемая + очень лагованая

Comment: disnake тоже самое типа discord.py????

Comment: типо там команды такие же? или это совсем другое

Comment: Это форк discord.py. Тоесть в основе лежит та же самая библиотека только переработана и улучшена